# Compress/Encode form values to short, readable string

Tags: javascript, compression

I have a very simple HTML form with ten toggles (`1`/`0`) and one select input with two-digit numbers as values. The result from the whole form could be written as a 12-digit number like `000060000111` (where the 5th and 6th digits represent the number from the select input).

My aim is to compress/encode this sequence using JavaScript into a short, human readable string with letters and numbers to reference the values of the form. A 6-digit string containing numbers and letters would be perfect (e.g. `An3K7d`). Ambiguous characters like `I` and `l` should be avoided.

I tried converting the sequence with Base64, but the output is even longer.

Comment: If you want to avoid ambiguities, you may want to use [base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) encoding instead of base64, which is desinged to avoid ambiguous characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, you can easily code that into three characters.

There are 1024 possible toggle settings and 100 possible two-digit numbers, so 102,400 possible values total. The cube-root of that is less than 47, so it can be represented in three characters chosen from a set of 47. You could use just upper and lower case letters, and leave out ones you don't like (like I, l, o, O, whatever), and still have plenty left. Or you can throw digits in there and use fewer letters. Whatever you prefer.

To do the encoding, simply convert the inputs into an integer in the range 0..102,399. It would just be a 10-bit number for the toggles, multiplied by 100, and then 0..99 added for the two-digit input.

Then encode that integer in base 47 by successively dividing by 47, taking the remainder as a digit, and using the quotient for the next division. To decode, recombine the base 47 digits by multiplying, and then extracting your input information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent explanation. I'm very new to this, but with your help I managed to write the encode/decode functions, which I'll post later.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Mark's excellent answer I solved my problem with the following code ([CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENrYXp)):

```js
// Base 47 characters
var chars = [
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J',
    'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'T', 'U',
    'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',
    'f', 'g', 'h', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 't',
    'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '2', '3', '4',
    '6', '7'
];

function encode(value) {
  // Get toggle values and convert binary to decimal
  var toggles = value.slice(0, value.length - 2); // string
  var decimal = parseInt(toggles, 2); // number (0..1023)

  //  Get two-digit select value
  var select = parseInt(value.slice(value.length - 2)); // number (0..99)

  //  Combine toggle and select values to a single integer
  var possibility = (decimal * 100) + select; // number (0..103499)

  var output = '';

  // Get  base47 value by successively dividing by 47,
  // taking the remainder as a digit, and using the quotient
  // for the next division
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var quotient = Math.floor(possibility/47);
    var remainder = possibility - (quotient * 47);
    possibility = quotient;
    output += chars[remainder];
  }

  return output; 
} // encode(value)

function decode(value) {
  var possibility = 0;

  // Loop through base47 string, beginning from the end
  // Recombine the base 47 digits by successively multiplying by 47
  for(var i = value.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var item = value[i];
    var remainder = chars.indexOf(value[i]);

    possibility = (possibility * 47) + remainder; 
  }

  // Convert number to string
  possibility = possibility.toString();

  //  Fill numbers < 3 digits with leading zeros
  while(possibility.length < 3) { possibility = '0' + possibility; }

  // Get toggles and select values from string
  var toggles = possibility.slice(0, possibility.length - 2); 
  var select = possibility.slice(possibility.length - 2); 

  // Convert toggles string to binary string and add leading zeros
  var binary = parseInt(toggles, 10).toString(2); 
  while(binary.length < 10) { binary = '0' + binary; } 

  // Return binary toggle values, followed by the select values
  return binary + select;
} // decode(value)
```